# "Error de compilación en Angular: no se puede encontrar el archivo 'bootstrap.css' y 'bootstrap.js' en la ruta especificada"

Tags: angular

Estoy teniendo problemas para usar `ng serve` en mi aplicación de Angular debido a dos errores que aparecen en el registro.

El primer error indica que la aplicación no puede encontrar el archivo `bootstrap.css` de Bootstrap en la ruta `Proyecto_FilomenoLautaro/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`.

El segundo error indica que la aplicación no puede encontrar el archivo `bootstrap.js` de Bootstrap en la ruta `Proyecto_FilomenoLautaro/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`

Ambos errores indican que el proceso de compilación no pudo encontrar los archivos de Bootstrap que se supone que deben estar en esas rutas.

He verificado que los archivos de Bootstrap y están instalados en mi proyecto y que las rutas son correctas en mi archivo `angular.json`. ¿Qué podría estar causando estos errores y cómo puedo solucionarlos para poder compilar mi aplicación correctamente?

Los errores:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'Proyecto_FilomenoLautaro/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in 'E:\Proyecto_Final\Proyecto_Final_FilomenoLautaro\Proyecto_FilomenoLautaro'

Error: Can't resolve 'Proyecto_FilomenoLautaro/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' in 'E:\Proyecto_Final\Proyecto_Final_FilomenoLautaro\Proyecto_FilomenoLautaro'
```

Mi versión de:
Angular Cli:15.2.7
Angular Core:15.2.8
node:18.16.0
Bootstrap:v5.3.0-alpha3

PD: Es mi primer publicación en Stack, disculpen si no esta tan bien. Soy novato. Gracias.

Comment: Intenta usando el CDN,  nunca he conseguido que se ejecute al instalarlo desde npm.  Agrega `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">` en tu index.html  debajo del otro link que aparece ahi

Comment: Agrega el contenido del archivo angular.json y el package.json

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo conseguí usando CDN. Pero cualquier otro metodo para tenerlo instalado sera bienvenido, probare otras formas tambien. Gracias de verdad.